# Is there any tool for combining front-end JS files in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filemerge

I have front-end JS files:

-js
   -a.js
   -b.js
   -c.js

and I request `http://example.com/js/all.js`, I will get a file with all contents of `a.js`, `b.js` and `c.js`.

Is there any library provides such function in NodeJS?

Answer (score 2):

You may use simple linux cat to concatenate all scripts into one.

```
cat ./a.js ./b.js ./c.js > all.js
```

Also you can execute this command from node.js.

Concatenating scripts to all.js with node.js (on air) not the best way because this will increase the server load.

Answer (score 2):

[require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) should offer the functionality you're looking for if the node `common.js` isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out anvil: https://github.com/arobson/anvil.js

It offers a highly configurable process for preparing a number of front end files, although I can't seem to find an API that can be used directly from your node application.